# for loop in case of square brackets

Tags: matlab, for-loop

I studied a code related to my work in which a `for` loop was used as shown below:

```
for jcyc=3:3:57
    [ddx, cycl_ind(jcyc)] = min(abs(jcyc-time_2));
end
```

Here `time_2 = 1×1800`.

In square brackets, the function of `ddx` and `cycl_ind(jcyc)` is not clear to me. For which purpose are the square brackets and `ddx`, `cycl_ind(jcyc)` inside it used?

Answer (score 0):

The meaningful part here is

```
[ddx, cycl_ind(jcyc)] = min(abs(jcyc-time_2));
```

Let's simplify that to understand how `min()` works in Matlab.

```
clear all;
a=[2,1,3];
val = min(a);
```

gives you val = 1 - minimal value.

```
clear all;
a=[2,1,3];
[val,pos] = min(a);
```

gives you val = 1, pos = 2 - minimal value and the index of that value. In that case min() will return 2 values.

```
clear all;
a=[2,1,3];
val,pos = min(a);
```

will give you an error:

```
Undefined function or variable 'val'.
```

You need to use brackets to get multiple output values from such functions and to store results in different variables.